# For Loop For Numerous Regression Models

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, regression

I have a database that looks like this. The Race, Age and Insurance variables are categorical, the symptom and Covid_pos variables are [0/1].

```
ID   RACE_GROUP_N Age_Group_N... Covid_pos  Asymptomatic  Fever  Cough ...
0     1               0            1             0        1      0
1     0               2            0             0        0      1
2     3               3            1             1        0      0
3     2               1            1             0        1      0
4     3               2            0             1        0      0
5     0               4            1             0        1      0
```

I want to run individual regression models for each symptom variables with the categorical variables, age, race and insurance. Each regression will be the same for each symptom; so for example, the regression models currently look like this:

```
asy_model = smf.logit("Covid_pos ~  Asymptomatic  + C(RACE_GROUP_N, Treatment(0))+ C(Age_Group_N, Treatment(0))+C(Insurance_Type_Group, Treatment(0))",
        data = df_merged2).fit()
asy_model_odds = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(asy_model.params), columns= ['OR'])
asy_model_odds['z-value']= asy_model.pvalues
asy_model_odds[['2.5%', '97.5%']] = np.exp(asy_model.conf_int())
asy_model_odds

fev_model = smf.logit("Covid_pos ~  Fever+ C(RACE_GROUP_N, Treatment(0))+ C(Age_Group_N, Treatment(0))+C(Insurance_Type_Group, Treatment(0))",
        data = df_merged2).fit()
fev_model_odds = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(fev_model .params), columns= ['OR'])
fev_model_odds ['z-value']= fev_model .pvalues
fev_model_odds [['2.5%', '97.5%']] = np.exp(fev_model .conf_int())
fev_model_odds
```

**Problem statement 1:** I want to create a for loop so I do not have to write this code 15+ times for each symptom variable.

**Problem statement 2:** I want the output of the for loop to express the results with the OR and 95% CI.Like so.

```
Symptom            Odds Ratio   LCB   UCB 
Asymptomatic      2.607       1.981 3.430
Fever             1.899       1.226 2.941
```

Comment: you could build a dictionary with the names of the models as keys and the model objects as values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would separate the symptoms and run separate regressions (as the purpose of a logit regression is precisely to identify the importance of all features/symptoms).

Anyway you could build a dictionary with the names and models as

```
all_models = {'name1': model_object1, 'name2': ... }
```

Then the loop would be

```
all_odds = dict()
for model_name, model in all_models.items():
    odds = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(model.params), columns=['OR'])
    odds['z-value'] = model.pvalues
    odds[['2.5%', '97.5%']] = np.exp(model.conf_int())
    all_odds['model_name'] = odds
```

Finally you can access the odds for each individual odds as with any dictionary, or you can build a master dataframe

```
all_odds = pd.concat(all_odds.values(), keys=all_odds.keys())
```

---

Update

I don't remember the syntax for statsmodels, but to populate the `all_models` dictionary you can use something like

```
all_models = dict()
all_models['asymptomatic'] = smf.logit(...).fit()
all_models['fever'] = smf.logit(...).fit()
```

Comment: Thanks! purpose of the model is to get the adjusted OR. What do you mean by "model_object1"? Can you please give an example of what would be in there?

Comment: When I use the Updated all models code, then run the loop and all_odds code, it returns the full output for just the last variable in the all_models code. For example, i would only get the output for fever, and it shows all of the output for age, race and insurance.